# iAd interfering with my SKScene class

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, iad

Sorry, the title of this question is a bit ambiguous.

So I have a SpriteKit game that is launched through a view controller. I also have an iAd that is displayed through that same view controller. When the game is paused, the iAd is displayed, and when the game is un-paused, I send an NSNotification to the view controller in order to hide the iAd.

My problem comes when a user presses the iAd. The iAd is displayed when the game is paused, and the game can be un-paused simply by taping the screen. So, when the user clicks the iAd (while the game is paused), the iAd opens to full screen while the game un-pauses itself.

I need a way that I can let my view controller know that when the iAd is displayed, any touch in a certain CGRect (the frame where the iAd is displayed) should not be received by the SKScene.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Let your scene conform to the `AdBannerViewDelegate` protocol. If the scene is the banner's  delegate you can implement a `BOOL` ivar in the scene `_bannerIsActive`. Then:

```
- (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave{
   _bannerIsActive = YES;
   return YES;
}
```

In your un-pause logic you need to check towards the BOOL and only restart the game if `_bannerActive == NO`.

And of course you need to set it to NO when the banner has finished its action:

```
- (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner{
   _bannerIsActive = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in a game I was making. I had the leaderboards button show up when the player lost, but also "tap anywhere to restart." So when I tapped the leaderboard button, the game started and ran behind the leaderboards. So I feel like my solution might pertain to yours.

Make an if statement that makes it so the game unpauses only if the user tapped somewhere AND didn't tap another object (the iAd).